# Laravel still expects to find deleted_at column after I remove softDelete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

I just removed softDelete from a table with this migration:

```
   Schema::table("items", function ($table) {
      $table->dropSoftDeletes();
   });
```

But now every query results in:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.deleted_at' in 'where clause'
```

Nowhere does the code explicitly refer to this column. Has it been cached somewhere, and if so, how to clear it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You also need to remove the trait from the model:

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting):

> To enable soft deletes for a model, use the  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait on the model