# Laravel - it is looking for a column "deleted_at" even if I didn't created that column

Tags: php, laravel

I am having this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `events` where `events`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

I didn't create a `deleted_at` column in that table but Laravel is looking for that column, how can I disable that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel still expects to find deleted\_at column after I remove softDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478645/laravel-still-expects-to-find-deleted-at-column-after-i-remove-softdelete)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478645/laravel-still-expects-to-find-deleted-at-column-after-i-remove-softdelete?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the trait from your `App\Event` model:

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting):

> To enable soft deletes for a model, use the
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes trait on the model

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you haven't removed the soft delete trait from your model (Event class):

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your Eloquent query look like? Are you using SoftDeletes? If not the above solutions are what you are looking for.

If you are using SoftDelete trait and have all columns in place then: 
I had the same issue when I used the `from` method on my model. There is also an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1206) on GitHub when using the `from` method.
My solution was to re-write my query without `from`.