# how to solve SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm working on database Eloquent Relationship One to one but after writing code, I'm getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'posts.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: `` select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` = 1 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 ``)

this code is for post table where I linked the user_id

***Post table migration***

```
class CreatePostTable extends Migration
{
   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

  
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

this is the user table where I have to link the post

***User model migration***

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

***User.php code***

```
 
public function post(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Post'); //select * from post where user_id = 1
    
}
```

and this is the route:

***Routes\web.php***

```
 Route::get('user/{id}/post', function ($id) {
     

    return User::find($id)->post;
 });
```

Comment: Check table's structure directly (via CLI or raw SQL) for correct column name. PS.  ```where `posts`.`user_id` = 1 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null``` - if 1st condition is true then 2nd is true too - so 2nd condition is excess.

Comment: What is the primary key for user table?

Comment: Primary key for user table is 'id=1'

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478645/laravel-still-expects-to-find-deleted-at-column-after-i-remove-softdelete

Comment: Thank you I tried it and boom it solved my problem @SenthilnadhanRamasamy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel still expects to find deleted\_at column after I remove softDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478645/laravel-still-expects-to-find-deleted-at-column-after-i-remove-softdelete)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Post` model probably uses Trait `SoftDeletes` which adds to query clause `deleted_at is null` when you call eloquent methods.

You have 2 solution for that:

1. Add to your migration (Create new migration),
   with `$table->softDeletes();` which adds that column - deleted_at.
2. Remove Trait `SoftDeletes` from `Post` model.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't created a `deleted_at` column in the `posts` table. If you create a `deleted_at` column in the `posts` table, then it will work.

Comment: This answer is incomprehensible. Please try to post a proper answer.